# Custom package does not exist in maven project

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, maven

I've been working on a bigger project for about a month now. It is a multi-module maven/java project. So far, I've had this "error" several times, but I've successfully resolved it after trying to launch the app a few times. Until now, I thought it was a bug in my IntelliJ Idea. Yesterday, the same problem happened to me again, and no matter how many times I tried to start the application, the same error happened to me again and again.

An error occurs when building the application:

This is the first error line I see:

```
package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
```

When I expand the error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ market-cruiser-back-end ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 23 source files to D:\programiranje\JAVA\Spring Projects\market-cruiser-project\market-cruiser-web-parent\market-cruiser-back-end\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserServiceImpl.java:[3,39] package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserServiceImpl.java:[4,39] package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserService.java:[3,39] package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserService.java:[4,39] package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserRepository.java:[3,39] package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserRepository.java:[11,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class User
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/RoleRepository.java:[3,39] package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/RoleRepository.java:[8,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Role
[ERROR] /D:/programiranje/JAVA/Spring Projects/market-cruiser-project/market-cruiser-web-parent/market-cruiser-back-end/src/main/java/com/marketcruiser/admin/user/UserServiceImpl.java:[37,12] cannot find symbol
```

More than 100 lines of such error codes.

Architecture of my project is:

```
market-cruiser-project -> market-cruiser-common
                       -> market-cruiser-web-parent -> market-cruiser-back-end
                                                    -> market-cruiser-front-end
```

This is pom.xml of `market-cruiser-project` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.marketcruiser</groupId>
    <artifactId>market-cruiser-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>market-cruiser-project</name>
    <description>Root project</description>

    <modules>
        <module>market-cruiser-common</module>
        <module>market-cruiser-web-parent</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

pom.xml of `market-cruiser-common` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.marketcruiser</groupId>
    <artifactId>market-cruiser-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>market-cruiser-common</name>
    <description>common library</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

pom.xml of `market-cruiser-web-parent` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.marketcruiser</groupId>
    <artifactId>market-cruiser-web-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>market-cruiser-web-parent</name>
    <description>parent spring web project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>market-cruiser-back-end</module>
        <module>market-cruiser-front-end</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.marketcruiser</groupId>
            <artifactId>market-cruiser-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

pom.xml of `market-cruiser-back-end` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.marketcruiser</groupId>
        <artifactId>market-cruiser-web-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>market-cruiser-back-end</artifactId>
    <name>market-cruiser-back-end</name>
    <description>market cruiser admin project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And pom.xml of `market-cruiser-front-end` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.marketcruiser</groupId>
        <artifactId>market-cruiser-web-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>market-cruiser-front-end</artifactId>
    <name>market-cruiser-front-end</name>
    <description>market-cruiser-front-end</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

What I tried to do in order to resolve the issue:

1. I used `@EntityScan({"com.marketcruiser.common.entity", "com.marketcruiser.admin.user"})` in my SpringBootApplication
2. I updated pom.xml to java version installed on my PC.
3. I tried to rebuild the app several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup, `market-cruiser-common` and `market-cruiser-web-parent` are two fully separate projects that don't have anything in common. Your current structure is not what you think it is, but instead this:

```
market-cruiser-project
market-cruiser-common
market-cruiser-web-parent -> market-cruiser-back-end
                          -> market-cruiser-front-end
```

`market-cruiser-common` and `market-cruiser-web-parent` should use `market-cruiser-project` as parent, not `spring-boot-starter-parent`. That should instead be the parent of `market-cruiser-project`. Then you get the structure you want.

Comment: Yes, `market-cruiser-common` and `market-cruiser-web-parent` are two fully separate projects and their parent is `market-cruiser-project`. I only use `market-cruiser-common` for modules like `User` and `Role` there that are common in `market-cruiser-back-end` and `market-cruiser-front-end`. The problem occurs when I try to import e.g. `User` from `market-cruiser-common` to `market-cruiser-back-end`. It says that `package com.marketcruiser.common.entity does not exist`.

So, you suggest me to change the parent in pom.xml to `market-cruiser-project` instead of `market-cruiser-starter-parent`?

Comment: I did everything as you said. It was also necessary for me to insert `<pluginManagement>` under the `<build>` in pom.xml of `market-cruiser-common`. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have only one question if you can answer: How is it possible that my project has worked without this problem so far?

Comment: @nikolaPantelic98 did you do a `mvn install` or a `mvn deploy` previously? Because that puts the artifact in the local / remote repository. As a result, the dependency will be resolved from the repository. The latest changes won't be available until you do another `mvn install` or `mvn deploy`. By making them part of one larger project, the dependency will be resolved from the project instead, which means all the latest changes will always be available.